# Duplicate Meta description on shared node across multiple subdomains

Tags: meta-tags

I have a drupal site with multiple subdomains which share a single node. I installed [Yoast SEO](https://www.drupal.org/project/yoast_seo) for Drupal and added title / description etc. for each node. Now the problem is that it shows same meta title and description for all sites (subdomain). Any idea on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that module (looks cool!), but it does depend on metatag, which is probably what's providing the title & description fields. The metatag module saves its configuration in a database table `metatag_config`, which is probably shared across all of your subdomains.

It looks like you can have tokens in your config, so for example, we use `[node:title] [site:name]` for our page title config. And if you wanted an unique title for each subdomain, you could just specify a separate site name for each one.

We use subdomains (www, m, staging, dev, etc) and we're fine to share the node's title & description across all of them. The thing we do want unique is the canonical meta tag, so if a search engine comes across duplicated content on a subdomain, it won't take anything away from the original. So we'll specify the full domain in the canonical url like this:

https://www.example.com/[current-page:url:path]